# how to remove double codes from the json string format using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I am new to JSON

`["Date.UTC(2011,10,29)","13"]` need to remove double quotes in the each date and frequency.
tried using below code.. but still see the double quotes.. What am I missing?

```
$json_string = json_encode($response);
echo $json_string;
```

Comment: you can't. JSON syntax REQUIRES the quotes around string keys/values.

Comment: that's not how json works, the double quotes are required

Comment: @MarcB I need to get a result like this.. tot converting to string will help.. but no luck :( [Date.UTC(2011,9,23),1],[Date.UTC(2011,9,24),1]

Comment: what are you needing to use this quote-less string for? You can NOT avoid having the quotes if you're using json. json requires them. if you don't have then quotes, then it's not json (thought it might be javascript still).

Comment: I have to use those strings data to insert in high-charts to show statistics.. hence i've to remove the double codes. How else I can go this.. have no idea. do help :(

Comment: When you decode the JSON in PHP the double quotes will automatically be gone.

Comment: @DarkAshelin $json = json_decode($response); i'm doing like this.. Is this the right way?? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need use JSON DECODE

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php

When you encode i need decode the json.

Comment: Can you throw some more light on this please.. I tried using decode too i got an error as  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be strin
wrote like this..
     $json = $response;
 var_dump(json_decode($json));
      var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
   echo $json;